# get css background property of gradient element by .css()

Tags: jquery, css, background

I'm trying to switch from gradient background to plain background of an element by using jquery.

For some reasons I can't use toggleClass and othe class methods, so I have to modify css properties of an element - background color in my case.

Problem is, that when I'm trying to receive current background css property, .css() method returns something weird.

I have en element with multiple background (gradient) properties, optimized for different browsers

```
 .element {
       background: #ce4f57 !important;
       background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ce4f57 0%, #b7333b 100%) !important;
       background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ce4f57), color-stop(100%, #b7333b)) !important;
       background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ce4f57 0%, #b7333b 100%) !important;
       background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ce4f57 0%, #b7333b 100%) !important;
       background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ce4f57 0%, #b7333b 100%) !important;
       background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ce4f57 0%, #b7333b 100%) !important;
       filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ce4f57', endColorstr='#b7333b', GradientType=0) !important;
     }
```

When I try to receive that property

```
 $('.element').css('background');
```

I get this:

```
 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(rgb(206, 79, 87) 0%, rgb(183, 51, 59) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hvZT/266/)

As far as I understand, it's compiled property? Can I get original css by js function?
If not pls advise how to write regexp to get first color of gradient, assuming there might be differenet compiled css in different browsers...

Comment: i say it returns the value, that YOUR SPECIFIC browser is currently using..

Comment: looks like that, but I need first color to change background from gradient to plain, how do i get it?

Comment: you mean you are looking for the very first value aka. background: #ce4f57 !important; ?

Comment: Why can't you use toggleClass and other class methods? What's the limitation?

Comment: because it supposed to be one function for different classes...noumerous different classes

Comment: Numerous different classes? Can you give us an example of what your real-life issue is? We might be able to help you better.

Comment: e.g. "jGrowl-notification highlight ui-corner-all orderAccepted"
the last one class - orderAccepted contains gradient, but the name of the class varies a lot (about 20 now) and more names can arrive, script should handle them

Comment: Do you need the actual color to be an inline style? or can it be the start (0%) of your gradient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to select the first point (0%) of the gradient you can do so by

```
var css = $('.element').css('background-image');
```

Then split it into a RGB value

```
var gradient = css.split('0%')[0].split('linear-gradient(')[1]
```

In Chrome and FF it works correctly. You can test it using the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6hvZT/277/

Update - That will be Cross browser compatible:

```
$("button").click(function(){    
    var css = $('.element').css('background-image');
    var bg_color;

    if ( css === 'none' ) {
        bg_color = $('.element').css('background-color');
    } else {
        bg_color = css.split('0%')[0].split('linear-gradient(')[1]                  
    }

    $('#css').html(bg_color);
});
```

Comment: your answer solves the problem (partially, for browsers that use linear-gradient property), but I was looking for general method of getting precompiled css

Comment: @ProstoTrader I've updated the solution to work in browsers that do not support linear gradients

Answer (score 0):

Your code just needed a little tweaking - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/6hvZT/267/

```
$("button").click(function(){    
    var css = $('.element').css('background-color'); // note the change
    $('#css').html(css);
});
```

In the fiddle the inline style should override the assigned class, but it looks like there is more at play here. It doesn't matter what the inline or applied style is, the click returns 'transparent' which is the inherited style. If you comment out the CSS then you get a return for the inline style.

I was able to use toggleClass() in this example - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/6hvZT/270/

```
$('#b1').click(function() {
    $('#foo').toggleClass('element1 element2');
});
```

Isn't that what your original question was?

Comment: css('background-color') returns rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) which is not the case at all - I have red background, not black. css('background') at least returns gradient...

Comment: Actually when I test css('background') it returns nothing in FF. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: I use chrome of couse

Comment: Actually the browser shouldn't matter. Are your visitors all going to be using Chrome?

Comment: downvote is becouse your solution works even worse then my question...nothing personal man, thanks for trying anyway

Comment: that's the problem that not all users use the same browser... some use IE :0

Comment: i get a transpanrent value as well. BUT if you comment out the background values, you get the red tone. that is, cause background overrides background-color. http://jsfiddle.net/honk1/6hvZT/269/

Comment: I can't change initial css of the clss

Comment: So, you're using background-color now? Or are you just doing that for those of us who test in something other than Chrome?

Comment: @ProstoTrader I added another example where toggleClass() works. You can toggle multiple classes from one call. Perhaps you need to state more of what you're looking to do in your original post so that we can approach this properly.

Comment: i cant toggle classes because there noumerous classes on the element and they are all different - I dont even know which one sets gradient at the moment

Comment: and of couse classes hold not just gradient but other css properties as well

Comment: Gotcha. I wish you luck trying to figure it out, sounds like some overly complex CSS.